# Is Drupal 8 with PostgreSQL supported?

Tags: 8, database

Is the new Drupal 8 supported/certified by the Drupal community to run on PostgreSQL?

This is the top hit,

https://www.drupal.org/node/2157455

I don't really know what that means here in the Open Source part as the majority of support is MySQL (or so it appears).

Answer (score 3):

it works and its even blazing fast.

tested on

```
drupal core 8.3.7
postgresql 9.6.3
amp stack - XAMPP
```

drupal case to follow on postgres drupal integration
https://www.drupal.org/node/2564307

Answer (score 1):

Did you not read the issue thread? or the last comment?   Which links to https://www.drupal.org/node/2564307  and says:

> As of September 2015 we have all tests passing the PostgreSQL CI bot (yay!). However, there are still some open issues around that should be fixed in terms of performance, security and for contrib land.

Drupal 8 Core will likely support PG. But, contrib modules typically use vendor specific SQL for complicated queries -- so per-module support will likely continue to be spotty.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what that means.  I suppose it means "Welcome to Open Source."

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you expect from the Drupal community. I can show you the answer but I can't understand it for you. Not every developer works with PG, MySQL, or SQL Server -- Drupal Core makes an effort to work with certain vendor databases; not all contributed modules make the same effort -- because not developers use those platforms or have other constraints. Yes drupal is open source so if you find a 3rd party module that is lacking support for PG you're free to contribute back to the community to enable better support for PG within that module.

Comment: I think that contrib module support is not "spotty", but will be quite good. There are still some module developers that will need to use SQL-specifics, but that should not be the case with the growing support for mongo and SQL Sever drivers in contrib and core trying to provide an equivalent for most things. The biggest worry would be that the pgsql driver in core does not support things that developers are used to such as using schemas or the newer JSON functionality. There is a contrib module for that (jsonfield) :-)

Comment: I disagree. I think cross db _vendor_ support for non-core modules is lacking. I tried using the Data module I think with a test sqlite database and drupal 7 core and the Data (may have been the Schema module) attempted to use a mysql specific query that was not supported by sqlite. This is 1 example off the top of my head from my real-world usage of drupal. I know there are others. Core is great! Contrib is literally built by a developer who works usually within 1 db engine and doesnt necessarily use the db api to the fullest.